# Why is my adsense RPM zero?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I've signed up for adsense, and I got approved. Google is serving ads on my website, so far I only have a few page visits, I don't think anyone clicked on my ads. Why is the RPM still zero? When will it change? Could someone point out some documentation to completely describe how and when google will pay us, and when updates will take place on the homepage of my google adsense account? Also the performance reports say "no data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Google’s own definition for RPM https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/112030?hl=en

As you can see it’s perfectly normal that your RPM is still zero since you haven’t gotten any earnings and therefore zero divided by whatever number of page views will always be zero.

I know it’s hard, especially at the beginning when you are all excited about starting to monetize your site. But I think the best advice I can give you is to not get too obsessed about constantly checking Adsense dashboard.

I’m not saying that Adsense isn’t transparent about how much they p
ay publishers, but they certainly follow a complex formula that involves a lot of variables. If you keep checking too often you’ll start seen things, like your RPM going up, or down, your CTR going up, down, etc. I’m not saying these numbers aren’t important either, I’m just saying you should focus on your website, on improving it in every way you can, in keeping up with your good content, etc. If you do that and your site proves to be useful to your readers Adsense earning will come.

After all its Google we are talking about, not some Russian website that was just launched (nothing against the Russian), so you can be quite certain that they won’t be ripping you off and that you’ll get paid fairly according to the value your website provides.

Comment: makes sense, it's just so confusing because they are supposed to "estimate" my earning before I earn anything, it wouldn't be estimating if they already know what I'm earning....but your definitely right, I won't be obsessed any more lol.

Answer (score 1):

> Google is serving ads on my website, so far I only have a few page visits, I don't think anyone clicked on my ads. Why is the RPM still zero?

Those visits could come from anyone including robots that are able to execute javascript. Also, a few page visits isn't enough to make a dollar on adsense. You want at least 1000 page visits a day from real people to make something unless your site has some kind of information that billions of people constantly want.

> When will it change? Could someone point out some documentation to completely describe how and when google will pay us, and when updates will take place on the homepage of my google adsense account?

Google pays about 30 days after the end of the month in which you earned $100 or more depending on your settings. They pay to your bank account.

They tend to update your earnings report every 15 minutes to every hour depending on your visitors.

> Also the performance reports say "no data"

That's because you haven't had a single visitor since midnight. This can happen too if ads do not appear in people's web browsers.